# 3D Arrays in C and Printing Its content

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to do something that should be simple. I am making an array that only has 1 element in it. Which is coordinates x y z

So I figured Id make an array with 1 row and 3 columns, 1 column for the x y and z. I don't need anymore rows because this number is going to be constantly updated and I don't need memory of the previous point, so its just going to be constantly overridden

so here is my array

```
 int coordinates[1][3] = {1,1,1};
```

and this is how I am trying to see if I built it correct and that the values print out.

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", coordinates[1][1],coordinates[1][2],coordinates[1][3] );
printf("\n");
```

My thinking that it will print Row 1 column 1, Row 1 Column 2, and row 1 column 3.

What is wrong with my thinking here? I'm not getting `1 1 1` as my result. I'm getting random numbers.

I'm not too familiar with C. This seem trivial and I'm starting to spin my wheels too much on it.

EDIT: MY PROCESS OF WORKING THINGS(Also see comment)

"This was the first thing I tried. Thinking back to arrays 101 and indexing is n-1 because It seemed like I was getting elements in random memory address outside the arrays bounds. Still did not work unfortunately im starting to beat my head against a wall."

I did try

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", coordinates[0][0],coordinates[0][1],coordinates[0][2] );
printf("\n");
```

but again i got random numbers

**CONCLUSION**

Ok I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. You all were right. I was looking in the wrong spot of my code. Thank you for your prompt responses. What was happening was I Originally called my coordinates as a float in my code. I didnt copy and past it here so I called it an int here. SO when I was trying to printf with %d it was trying to print an int for a float causing the messed up results. I switched the %d to %f (which i was unaware how the printf worked like that i guess) and it worked!. Green horn mistake and im sorry for it! Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be indexed as cordinates[0][0], cordinates[0][1], cordinates[0][2] because array indexing usually starts at 0.
here  cordinates[1][3], means row size is one but it is indexed using 0. similary columns are indexed from 0 to 3. i.e. 0 to size-1

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. Thinking back to arrays 101 and indexing is n-1 because It seemed like I was getting elements in random memory address outside the arrays bounds. Still did not work unfortunately im starting to beat my head against a wall.

Comment: @CoffeePeddlerIntern printf("%d%d%d",coordinates[0][0],coordinates[0][1],coordinates[0][2]); should work fine. code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that array index starts from 0 in C, this rule applies to multiple-dimensional arrays as well.

For an array `int coordinates[1][3]`, its elements are `coordinates[0][0]`,  `coordinates[0][1]` and `coordinates[0][2]`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", coordinates[0][0],coordinates[0][1],coordinates[0][2] );
```

As the index starts from zero not one.